# Como cargar el resultado de una query en una grilla Datatable a través de una función?

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

Buenos tardes a todos.

Tengo un programa PHP con una opción de menú "Reporte". Cuando se ingresa a esta opción, se depliegan dos input, un botón Buscar y una tabla para desplegar los registros.

Esta funcionalidad debe cumplir con lo siguiente:

a) Que cuando el usuario ingrese a esta opción, los input contengan por default la fecha del día actual y en función de eso, se ejecute una consulta a la base de datos y retorne los registros en el rango de fechas y los despliegue en la tabla; todo lo anterior en forma automática.

b) Una vez desplegados los datos, el usuario puede cambiar el rango de fecha, modificando las fechas de los input y presionar el botón Buscar, se realiza una nueva consulta a la base de datos, se retornan los registros y se despliegan en la tabla.

Tengo implementado la solución, la cual satisface los comportamientos a) y b), pero dado que estoy utilizando como grilla un componente externo (src="js/datatables.min.js"), se genera el siguiente comportamiento no deseado en el despliegue en la grilla (tabla):

[image: Grilla de registros]

El combo Mostrar, propio de la grilla, no funciona.

El cuadro de texto Buscar, propio de la grilla, no funciona.

Al pie de la grilla, lado izquierdo, no se muestra la información de cantidades de registros. Al lado derecho, no se activan las flechas para desplazarse por las páginas de la grilla.

El código del front es el siguiente:
    


    
        
        REPORTE

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/personalizado.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dialogbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            parent.document.getElementById("loader").style.display='none';  //INVOCA FUNCION QUE OCULTA LOADER  MOSTRADO DESDE LA VENTANA PADRE (MENU3.PHP)
            $('#usuarios').DataTable(
            {
                "language": 
                {
                            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                            "sUrl":            "",
                            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                            "oPaginate": 
                            {
                                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                                "sLast":     "Último",
                                "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                            },
                            "oAria": 
                            {
                                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                            }
                },
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
            });

            $(function($){
                $.datepicker.regional['es'] = 
                {
                    closeText: 'Cerrar',
                    prevText: '<Ant',
                    nextText: 'Sig>',
                    currentText: 'Hoy',
                    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
                    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
                    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
                    weekHeader: 'Sm',
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    firstDay: 1,
                    isRTL: false,
                    showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    yearSuffix: ''
                };
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
            });

            $("#datepicker_desde").datepicker(
                {
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

            $("#datepicker_hasta").datepicker(
                {
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

            buscar_registros_boton();
        });

        function cambia_formato_datepicker(cadena)
        {
                var f=cadena;
                dia=f[0]+f[1];
                mes=f[3]+f[4];
                ano=f[6]+f[7]+f[8]+f[9];
                var fechaformat=ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
                return fechaformat;
        };

        function buscar_registros_boton()
        {
            var fechas ="fechadesde="+$("#datepicker_desde").val()+"&fechahasta="+$("#datepicker_hasta").val(); 
            console.log("Fechas:"+fechas);  

            $.ajax( 
            {                                                       
                url:"../querys/report_movimientos.php",
                data: fechas, 
                type:"POST",                        
                dataType: "json",
                success:
                function(resp)
                {
                    $("#datos").html("");

                    for(var i=0;i<resp.nfilas;i++)
                    {   //DESPLIEGA DATOS DE UNA FILA
                        $("#datos").append("<tr>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][0] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][1] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][2] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][3] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][4] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][5] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][6] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][7] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][8] + "</td>"+
                                      "</tr>");                                                     
                    };                                                          
                }
            });
        };

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="relleno_superior" style="width: 100%; height: 48px"></div>

    <div class="encabezado" style="font-family: Arial; font-size:40px; text-align: center; height: 30px;">
        Reporte de Movimientos de Mercaderías
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; font-family: Arial; font-size:14px; background-color: #2980b9; color: #ecf0f1;text-align: right">
        <?php echo "Usuario Logueado:[".$_SESSION['nombre']." ]";?>         
    </div>      
    <!-- BLOQUE PARA FECHA DESDE Y FECHA HASTA -->
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; font-family: Arial; font-size:14px; background-color: #2980b9; color: #ecf0f1;text-align: left">
        Rango de Fechas del Reporte:
        <input type="text" id="datepicker_desde" name="txtfecha_desde" style="width:80px" placeholder="Fecha Desde">
        <input type="text" id="datepicker_hasta" name="txtfecha_hasta" style="width:80px" placeholder="Fecha Hasta">
        <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="buscar_registros_boton()">
    </div>  

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  class="display" id="usuarios">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Tipo Mov.</th>
                <th>Movimiento</th>
                <th>Articulo</th>
                <th>Bodega 1</th>
                <th>Bodega 2</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="datos">
            <!--    AQUI SE INSERTAN LOS REGISTROS EN FORMA DINÁMICA-->
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Tipo Mov.</th>
                <th>Movimiento</th>
                <th>Articulo</th>
                <th>Bodega 1</th>
                <th>Bodega 2</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
```

Por ajax se invoca el php que se encarga se hacer la consulta a la base de datos, "report_movimientos.php", el cual retorna en un array los registros a desplegar y la cantidad de registros:

```
$info["filas"]=$filas;
$info["nfilas"]=$i;
echo json_encode($info);
```

$filas es un array que contiene cada campo que retorna la consulta a la base de datos.
Entiendo que estos problemas en la grilla se deben a que cuando en el body del html se instancia la tabla (grilla) y se termina de cargar el DOM, los registros que se meterán en ella aún no existen, por lo que los parámetros de la tabla quedan en "0". El posterior llenado de la tabla, desde la función, mete los registros a la tabla, pero no altera los parámetros internos de la tabla instanciada no se ven actualizados.
En función de lo anterior es que he tratado de instanciar desde dentro de la función "buscar_registros_boton()" la tabla completa, pero me arroja error. Lo que traté de implementar y el error es lo siguiente:

```
        function buscar_registros_boton()
        {
            var fechas ="fechadesde="+$("#datepicker_desde").val()+"&fechahasta="+$("#datepicker_hasta").val(); 
            console.log("Fechas:"+fechas);  

            $("#cuerpo").append("<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  class="display" id="usuarios">"+
                                "<thead>"+
                                "<tr>"+
                                "<th>Id</th>"+
                                "<th>Tipo Mov.</th>"+
                                "<th>Movimiento</th>"+
                                "<th>Articulo</th>"+
                                "<th>Bodega 1</th>"+
                                "<th>Bodega 2</th>"+
                                "<th>Cantidad</th>"+
                                "<th>Fecha</th>"+
                                " <th>Usuario</th>"+
                                "<th></th>"+
                                "</tr>"+
                                "</thead>"+
                                "<tbody id="datos">"

            $.ajax( 
            {                                                       
                url:"../querys/report_movimientos.php",
                data: fechas, 
                type:"POST",                        
                dataType: "json",
                success:
                function(resp)
                {
                    $("#datos").html("");

                    for(var i=0;i<resp.nfilas;i++)
                    {   //DESPLIEGA DATOS DE UNA FILA
                        $("#datos").append("<tr>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][0] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][1] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][2] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][3] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][4] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][5] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][6] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][7] + "</td>"+
                                                    "<td>" + resp.filas[i][8] + "</td>"+
                                      "</tr>");                                                     
                    };                                                          
                }
            });

            $("#cuerpo").append("<tfoot>"+
                                "<tr>"+
                                "<th>Id</th>"+
                                "<th>Tipo Mov.</th>"+
                                "<th>Movimiento</th>"+
                                "<th>Articulo</th>"+
                                "<th>Bodega 1</th>"+
                                "<th>Bodega 2</th>"+
                                "<th>Cantidad</th>"+
                                "<th>Fecha</th>"+
                                " <th>Usuario</th>"+
                                "<th></th>"+
                                "</tr>"+
                                "</tfoot>"
                                );

        };
```

El error que arroja es:

[image: ERROR INSTANCIANDO LA GRILA DESDE DENTRO DE LA FUNCIÓN]

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Aprender más]  rep_movimientos.php:103:45

La línea a la que hace referencia es:

[image: LÍNEA DEL ERROR]

Revisé y no falta ningún ")".

Lo anterior me hace pensar que no se puede instanciar la grilla desde dentro de la función, por un tema de la forma como está implementada la grilla (Datatable) o bien, estoy cometiendo un error sistemático del que no me he dado cuenta aún cuál es.

NOTA: Cuando en otra funcionalidad que tengo, instancio la tabla y meto los registros en la misma secuencia, la tabla queda bien cargada y sus parámetros bien actualizados, por ejemplo:

[image: Parámetros de la tabla bien actualizados]

La instancia y carga de los registros se hizo de la siguiente forma:

```
<body>
    <?php 
        $con=conectar();
        $sql = "SELECT id_aplicacion, aplicacion, descripcion FROM aplicaciones";
        $q = mysqli_query( $con, $sql) or die("Problemas al ejecutar la consulta");
     ?> 
     <div id="relleno_superior" style="width: 100%; height: 48px"></div>

    <div class="encabezado" style="font-family: Arial; font-size:40px; text-align: center; height: 30px;">
        Mantenedor de Aplicaciones
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; font-family: Arial; font-size:14px; background-color: #2980b9; color: #ecf0f1;text-align: right">
        <?php echo "Usuario Logueado:[".$_SESSION['nombre']." ]";?>         
    </div>

    <div id="relleno_inferior" style="width: 100%; height: 10px"></div>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  class="display" id="usuarios">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Aplicacion</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
            {
        ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $datos["id_aplicacion"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $datos["aplicacion"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $datos["descripcion"];?></td>
                <td>
                    <img src="img/edit_16x16.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="editar_aplicacion('<?php echo $datos["id_aplicacion"];?>')"/>   

                    <img src="img/eliminar_16x16.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="eliminar_aplicacion('<?php echo $datos["id_aplicacion"];?>')"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            }
            //mysqli_close();
        ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Aplicacion</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>    
    </table>
```

Estoy consciente de que me he extendido bastante, pero la idea era dejar claridad sobre el problema que tengo y sobre el cual estoy pidiendo que si alguien sabe cómo puedo superar el problema que planteo, me pueda dar una mano; le estaré muy agradecido. A todos, muchas gracias.

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

En base a lo que me ha sugerido Pablo Contreras, he modificado el código, pero creo que no he entendido completamente cómo funciona la implementación que me sugiere. En función de esto, te pido por favor Pablo Contreras que me puedas dar una mano, pues por lo que mencionaste, ya tienes un camino recorrido con este plugin. Los cambios que hice fueron los siguientes:

Modifiqué la función "buscar_registros_boton()" y quedó así:

```
        function buscar_registros_boton()
        {
            var fechas ="fechadesde="+$("#datepicker_desde").val()+"&fechahasta="+$("#datepicker_hasta").val(); 

            $('#usuarios').DataTable( 
            {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,

                "ajax": {
                        "url": "../querys/report_movimientos.php",
                        "dataSrc": "fechas"
                      },
                "columns": [
                                { "data": "id" },
                                { "data": "tipo_mov" },
                                { "data": "movimiento" },
                                { "data": "articulo" },
                                { "data": "bodega_1" },
                                { "data": "bodega_2" },
                                { "data": "cantidad" },
                                { "data": "fecha" },
                                { "data": "usuario" }
                           ]
            });

        };
```

En el body del html, la tabla quedó así:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  class="cell-border"  id="usuarios">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Tipo Mov.</th>
                <th>Movimiento</th>
                <th>Articulo</th>
                <th>Bodega 1</th>
                <th>Bodega 2</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Tipo Mov.</th>
                <th>Movimiento</th>
                <th>Articulo</th>
                <th>Bodega 1</th>
                <th>Bodega 2</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

El PHP que invoca el ajax y que realiza la consulta a la BD, quedó así:

```
<?php
require_once ("funciones/conexiones.php");
$fecha_desde=$_POST["fechadesde"];
$fecha_hasta=$_POST["fechahasta"];
$con = conectar();

$sql = "SELECT m.id_movmerc as id, b.bodega as  bodega_o, z.bodega as bodega_d, a.articulo as articulo,
               t.tip_movimiento as tip_mov, o.movimiento as movimiento, m.cantidad as cantidad, m.fecha as fecha, u.usuario as usuario
        FROM movmerc m, bodegas b, articulos a, bodegas z, tipo_movimientos t, movimientos o, usuarios u
        WHERE m.id_bodega_o=b.id_bodega and m.id_bodega_d=z.id_bodega and m.id_articulo=a.id_articulo and
              m.id_movimiento=o.id_movimiento and m.id_usuario=u.id_usuario and m.id_tip_movimiento=t.id_tip_movimiento and
              m.fecha BETWEEN '$fechadesde' AND '$fechahasta'";         
$q=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$filas=array();
$detalle=array();
$i=0;
while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
{
    $detalle[0]=$datos["id"];
    $detalle[1]=$datos["bodega_o"];
    $detalle[2]=$datos["bodega_d"];
    $detalle[3]=$datos["articulo"];
    $detalle[4]=$datos["tip_mov"];
    $detalle[5]=$datos["movimiento"];
    $detalle[6]=$datos["cantidad"];
    $detalle[7]=$fecha;
    $detalle[8]=$datos["usuario"];
    $filas[$i]=$detalle;
    $i=$i+1;
};
$info["filas"]=$filas;
echo json_encode($info);
?>
```

No sé si estoy pasando mal los datos devueltos desde el php que hace la consulta o qué problema hay. Cuando ejecuto, aparece el siguiente mensaje en la consola:

[image: Error Datatables con ajax]

Por favor, Pablo, si me puedes ayudar, te estaré muy agradecido.

***ACTUALIZACIÓN 12-05-2017 (madrugada)***.

En base a la sugerencia de JuankGlezz, implementé lo que indicaba la página que me cita (http://refreshmymind.com/datatables-dom-php-ajax-mysql-datasources/). En la implementación del ejemplo, utilicé la consulta  a una sola tabla en la BD y esto funcionó a la perfección, verificándose lo que indicaba la página sugerida. El problema surge en lo siguiente:

***PROBLEMA 1)*** Trato de pasar un parámetro hacia el php que realizará la consulta a la BD. Implementé lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Datatables - Server-Side processing using PHP&MySQL and Ajax|RefreshMyMind.Com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">            
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Data Source : Server-Side processing using PHP&MySQL and Ajax</h1>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="users" class="display" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>CEDULA</th>
    <th>NOMBRES</th>
    <th>APELLIDOS</th>
    <th>USUARIO</th>
    <th>PASSWORD</th>
    <th>TELEFONO</th>
    <th>DIRECCION</th>
    <th>ALTA</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>CEDULA</th>
    <th>NOMBRES</th>
    <th>APELLIDOS</th>
    <th>USUARIO</th>
    <th>PASSWORD</th>
    <th>TELEFONO</th>
    <th>DIRECCION</th>
    <th>ALTA</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
//LAS columns DEBEN SER IGUAL A LOS NOMBRES DE LOS CAMPOS DEVUELTOS POR LA BD.
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fechas ="fechadesde="+"11-05-2017"; 
    $('#users').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id_usuario"},
            {"data": "cedula"},
            {"data": "nombres"},
            {"data": "apellidos"},
            {"data": "usuario"},
            {"data": "password"},
            {"data": "tel"},
            {"data": "dir"},
            {"data": "fecha_alta"}
        ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: '../querys/backtables.php',
            data: fechas,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json"
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

AL ejecutar, arroja un error. Al revisar en la consola, aparece lo siguiente:

Mirando el POST:

[image: Error en el envío del parametro "fechadesde" en el ajax]

Como se visualiza, el parámetro que se trata de pasar el PHP que hará la consulta a la BD, pasa mal, pues pasa desglosado letra por letra y no como habitualmente pasa en ajax como una variable con un valor concreto.

Ahora, si visualizo la respuesta, se ve la variable fechadesde no existe en el back:

[image: Mensaje de error en el back]

***PROBLEMA 2)*** Tiene que ver que en el ejemplo que me referencia , el PHP que está en el back realiza la consulta en una sola tabla de la BD (MyTable). En mi caso, yo realizo una consulta sobre varias tablas:

```
$sql = "SELECT m.id_movmerc as id, b.bodega as  bodega_o, z.bodega as bodega_d, a.articulo as articulo,
               t.tip_movimiento as tip_mov, o.movimiento as movimiento, m.cantidad as cantidad, m.fecha as fecha, u.usuario as usuario
        FROM movmerc m, bodegas b, articulos a, bodegas z, tipo_movimientos t, movimientos o, usuarios u
        WHERE m.id_bodega_o=b.id_bodega and m.id_bodega_d=z.id_bodega and m.id_articulo=a.id_articulo and
              m.id_movimiento=o.id_movimiento and m.id_usuario=u.id_usuario and m.id_tip_movimiento=t.id_tip_movimiento and
              m.fecha BETWEEN '$fechadesde' AND '$fechahasta'";
```

¿Cómo se implementa en el PHP del back esta situación que planteo?

Estimado Juan, si fueras tan amable de orientarme cómo poder solucionar estos dos problemas, te estaré enormemente agradecido. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

***ACTUALIZACIÓN 12-05-2017 (en la tarde):***

Con respecto del Problema 1 que había reportado en la madrugada de hoy, pasar el parámetro en el ajax de Datatables hacia el php backend de la consulta a la BD, logré solucionarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//LAS columns DEBEN SER IGUAL A LOS NOMBRES DE LOS CAMPOS DEVUELTOS POR LA BD.
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fechad ="11-05-2017"; 
    var fechah ="12-05-2017"; 
    $('#users').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id_usuario"},
            {"data": "cedula"},
            {"data": "nombres"},
            {"data": "apellidos"},
            {"data": "usuario"},
            {"data": "password"},
            {"data": "tel"},
            {"data": "dir"},
            {"data": "fecha_alta"}
        ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '../querys/backtables.php',                
            "type": 'POST',
            "data": {fechadesde: fechad,
                     fechahasta: fechah},
            dataType: "json"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Revisando en la consola de firefox developer, se visualiza:

[image: Post]

Ahora seguiré con los esfuerzos para resolver el Problema 2; si alguien puede aportar, muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: te sugeriria usar las opciones que brinda `dataTables`, puesto que despues que empece a usar el modo [`server-side`](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) y sus filtrados todo me ha funcionado de maravilla.

Comment: Estimado Pablo Contreras, muchas gracias por tu sugerencia. Me leí la documentación y traté de implementar, pero parece que algo no he captado de la documentación, pues no me resulta. En el cuerpo de la consulta original, puse ACTUALIZACIÓN, desde donde comienzo la explicación de la implementación que hice a partir de tu sugerencia y por favor te pido que puedas dar una mano y orientarme qué es lo que estoy implementando mal. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: de nada amigo, utiliza Google Chrome para detectar mejor los errores. [Acá un ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXLqB.png).

Comment: @JuncoFuerte yo no he usado `server-side` en PHP espero esto pueda ayudarte (contenido en ingles) https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/

Comment: Estimado Pablo Contreras, por supuesto que utilizo google chrome para monitorear los errores, aunque el que más ocupo es FireFox Developer, tal como aparece en los printscreen que puse más arriba.

Comment: Estimado JuankGlezz, muchas gracias por la referencia que me diste, ha sido muy útil para tratar de solucionar el problema que tengo. Seguí el ejemplo que aparece en dicha página y funcionó perfectamente, pero al tratar de adaptarla a mi requerimiento tengo dos problemas que no he podido dar cómo solucionarlo:
1) Cuál es la forma correcta de enviar un parámetro en el ajax dentro del Datatables. 
2) En el ejemplo de la página que me citas, corresponde a la consulta a una sola tabla; pero cómo hacer cuando hay varias tablas?

En el cuerpo de la pregunta he puesto lo que implementé. Gracias.